# Is there a way to make a windowed fullscreen mode in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the window to be my resolution but still have the top bar appear. Just like you maximise a window.
This is what I have so far.

```py
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
display_info = pygame.display.Info()
self.width, self.height = display_info.current_w, display_info.current_h
self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.NOFRAME)
```

but it seems to not work and only fullscreen the window to my resolution. What am I missing?

Comment: then what do I do, and why has this been closed. the question it was similiar to was just to maximise "fullscreen" not have the top bar, please open the question up.

Comment: *"I want the window to be my resolution but still have the top bar appear."* - `pygame.NOFRAME` removes the frame and to bar. Even more this is not possible. Either you fullscreen mode with your resolution or window mode with the screen resolution of the OS.

Comment: display_info = pygame.display.Info()
        self.width, self.height = display_info.current_w, display_info.current_h - 50
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

Comment: Is tihis an answer? Calling `pygame.display.set_mode` twice doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid automatic resolution adjustment by pygame.FULLSCREEN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156731/how-to-avoid-automatic-resolution-adjustment-by-pygame-fullscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the window to be in fullscreen mode using this:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, FULLSCREEN)
```

If you have black borders around, you can make the window to fill the entire screen, leaving as few black borders as possible (depending of the relative screen and window [ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_aspect_ratio)), by the use of the pygame 2.0.0 flag `SCALED`:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size, FULLSCREEN|SCALED)
```

If you still want to delete the remaining borders, rescale your window:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

info = pygame.display.Info()
w = info.current_w
h = info.current_h

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h), FULLSCREEN|SCALED)
```