# How to avoid automatic resolution adjustment by pygame.FULLSCREEN?

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I am using pygame to create an application that needs a square screen, 800x800. It works fine when it's windowed i.e. when I simply do:

```
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
```

or

```
flags = NOFRAME
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), flags)
```

But when I use the fullscreen flag, my game window gets stretched to a widescreen resolution, making it non-square and also stretched to fit in fullscreen. What I think it's doing is it's automatically picking the closest resolution from the list of supported resolutions:

```
print(pygame.display.list_modes())
[(1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1680, 1050), (1680, 1050), (1680, 1050), (1600, 900), (1600, 900), (1600, 900), (1440, 900), (1440, 900), (1440, 900), (1440, 576), (1440, 576), (1440, 576), (1440, 576), (1440, 480), (1440, 480), (1440, 480), (1440, 480), (1440, 480), (1400, 1050), (1400, 1050), (1400, 1050), (1366, 768), (1366, 768), (1366, 768), (1360, 768), (1360, 768), (1360, 768), (1280, 1024), (1280, 1024), (1280, 1024), (1280, 1024), (1280, 960), (1280, 960), (1280, 960), (1280, 800), (1280, 800), (1280, 800), (1280, 768), (1280, 768), (1280, 768), (1280, 720), (1280, 720), (1280, 720), (1280, 600), (1280, 600), (1280, 600), (1152, 864), (1152, 864), (1152, 864), (1152, 864), (1024, 768), (1024, 768), (1024, 768), (1024, 768), (800, 600), (800, 600), (800, 600), (800, 600), (720, 576), (720, 576), (720, 576), (720, 480), (720, 480), (720, 480), (640, 480), (640, 480), (640, 480), (640, 480), (640, 400), (640, 400), (640, 400), (512, 384), (512, 384), (512, 384), (400, 300), (400, 300), (400, 300), (320, 240), (320, 240), (320, 240), (320, 200), (320, 200), (320, 200)]
```

But what I'd like it to do is for the window to remain unstretched i.e. remain in the same size as it is as using the pygame.NOFRAME flag or no flag, and to remain square (1:1 aspect ratio). I need it to be fullscreen, so the areas outside the 800x800 window can just be black areas.

I've looked around but I can't find a way to avoid this automatic adjustment that pygame does when going fullscreen. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe you could add some padding if the resolution is not square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fullscreen mode, you do not need to use `NOFRAME`, because this flag just removes the top bar, which is not visible in fullscreen mode.

You have several options when using fullscreen:

1. Scale the window to make it occupy the entire screen, leaving black areas in order to keep the window ratio. It looks like this:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,800), FULLSCREEN|SCALED)
```

[image]

---

2. Leave black areas around the window. Simply use the `FULLSCREEN` flag alone.

In this situation, depending on your platform, your entire screen can either be resized (second image), or not be changed; in this case you will have black borders around the window (first image).

I think that the platform that you are using prefers to adapt your screen resolution, to prevent from having black borders around, resulting in stretching the PyGame window (second image). If it is the case, then prefer the first solution, as it also prevents from several notifications or problems coming from the strange resolution change.

Sometimes your system will always remove the black borders, especially in PyGame 2.0.x. In this case,  if you still want the black borders, you can use [this code](https://github.com/D-00-python/black-borders-around-game) to add them back.

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800), FULLSCREEN)
```

[image]

or

[image]

---

3. You can also use this code to define a PyGame window whose size is your screen resolution:

```py
size = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size.current_w, size.current_h), FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the behavior seems to be very different depending on the system. The first image in option 2 is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. However on my system (pygame 2.0.1 Windows 10), using the FULLSCREEN flag alone results in something like option 1, where there is a lot of white space added on the right making it like a widescreen window. Using FULLSCREEN | SCALED keeps the 1:1 aspect ratio but stretches it to fit the height of my screen. In pygame 1.9.6, FULLSCREEN keeps the 1:1 aspect ratio and leaves black spaces on all 4 sides but it's still stretched (looks like 1000x1000).

Comment: OK, I thought what worried you was that your window was stretched X, but not Y, or vice versa. So you want to keep the black borders? Why? Isn't the rendering better when you play on a large screen? If you want to keep the borders from 1.9.6, then you can use PyGame 1.9.6...

Comment: I wanted the black borders simply because it suit the game's retro aesthetic better. I will indeed use 1.9.6, although I don't know what caused the behavior to change between versions and it doesn't seem to be a documented change. I know what I wanted is very unusual - your answer was still very helpful in understanding how `set_mode` should work in general.

Comment: Ok you can also use [this technique](https://github.com/D-00-python/black-borders-around-game) to keep borders around the game.

Comment: New link even though the old one should redirect: https://github.com/d-002/black-border-around-game